# The elder scrolls v thieves guild special jobs not working (ps4)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In my play through of the thieves guild i hav e finished the entire main missions for it and have completed many 'small' jobs from delvin and vex but nothing seems to activate the special jobs. i had a dialogue with delvin but skipped it by accident, my characters said he was ready for a whiterun special job but nothing happened after. i have 1 merchant, the statue of nocturnal and that is all the noticeable changes the guild. 
Solitude - IIIIIIIIII =10
Riften - IIIIIIII = 8
Whiterun - IIIIIIIII =9
Windhelm - IIIIIIIIIII = 11 
Markarth - IIIIIII = 7

this is the small jobs i have done in each hold, (i know that riften dosent matter) Im not sure if it is a mod im using that is bugging it, which it shouldnt but if anyone can help i would appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using mods, I would say it is safe to say that they are the reason why you can't get the achievement, because I'm pretty sure that achievements are disabled when using mods Bethesda did that for Fallout 4.

Comment: would the mods also be the reason why i cant do the quest

Comment: yes i would  say so

Comment: mod can mess up the game

Comment: if i remove the mods will it work or no?

Comment: yes if you start a new character without mods no if just you remove the mods the glitch will still be there unfortunitly

Comment: i hope this was helpful

Comment: I tried removing the mod which of course didnt work, i dont really mid though seeing as it dosent affect the game too much

Comment: removing the mod never really works was my answer help?